# Using Strings for File name or File path?

Tags: android, string

Ok so this is probably dumb question but I just can't seem to find a way how to do it.
How can I use string that I already defined in my Activity, for a file name or file path?
I passed this data using Intents

```
 String filepath=intent.getStringExtra("PATH");
 String ringname=intent.getStringExtra("NAME");
```

How can I use these two strings in this case

```
new File(rpath, "Nature Sounds.mp3");rpath.mkdirs(); // Path to create file, to use string ringname instead "nature Sounds.mp3"
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s1a64); // file path in Ressources, to use string ringname instead (R.raw.naturesound)
```

Comment: Replace `R.raw.s1a64` with string filepath

Comment: see my ans beautiful.......

Comment: @BhanuSharma That is what I am asking. How to pass string in my code.

Comment: you want to convert string into the file

Comment: see my ans i think this u want

Comment: `intent.putExtra("PATH", R.raw.s1a64);`
I am working on ringtone app, so I passed datas

Comment: ohkkk then change it into the string first then pass and then again convert it into the file of u want

Comment: you want to open an input stream on a file? a FileInputStream?

Comment: No no no...I want this `"Nature Sounds.mp3"` To be replaced by string 
` String ringname=intent.getStringExtra("NAME");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then get that string in other activity like

```
String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH").trim();
File f = new File(s1);
```

and then pass this string into your code

Comment: ohk so u found ans :)